# How can I show (e.g in the mode-line) the current keyboard layout?

Tags: mode-line, keyboard-layout

```
Linux Mint 20.2
Emacs 27.2
```

I have two Keyboard Layouts: US, RU.

[image]

Example of input text on 2 languages:
[image]

Is it possible, in mode-line to print current keyboard layout? E.g. **US**.

The ideal to show keyboard layout's icon.
Smt like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you using Gnome? Or something else?

Comment: @NickD Linux Mint 20.2 Cinamone

Comment: See if the following shell command works on your system: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources mru-sources`. If it produces any output at all, what does it say when the current keyboard layout is `US`? What does it say if it is `RU`?

Comment: Input method as defined by the OS? That depends on your setup, so more information is needed.  In the end, you'll need to call some shell script or command. Now let me address other somehow related aspects. If you type in russian, you should never have that input method selected when using emacs. Emacs should always be used with a latin-based input method selected on the OS level.  Emacs also provides input methods, evaluate `(setq default-input-method "russian-computer")`. You may find this emacs package useful (disclaimer, I'm the author): https://github.com/aadcg/emacs-yeis.

Comment: @NickD Equals result: "@a(ss) []"

Comment: WIth either keyboard layout? There is no difference?

Comment: It seems you're using GNOME. I believe that, by default, the top bar (where the date and setting are locations) shows which input method is selected. You can also choose a keybinding to toggle between the two.

Comment: Right, I see you're toggling with Win-Space. Привет! The issue now is that you can't use Emacs anymore when the RU input method is selected. Look at my comment above for suggestions.

Comment: @NickD Yes , no difference

Comment: @NickD I updated my post

Comment: @aadcg: strictly speaking, it's not true that you cannot use emacs. If I want to enter text in a buffer, I can switch keyboard layouts and enter my text in whatever language I've chosen. Executing commands *is* a bit harder, I admit :-)

Comment: @aadcg I updated my post.

Comment: @NickD, you're correct. I find that executing commands is the heart of Emacs, and toggling the input method on the OS level is tiring. But this is opinion-based of course.

Comment: @a_subscriber I see. I'm afraid the question, as it stands now, is hardly related to Emacs. I'm sure there's a hack to have what you want displayed on Emacs. But, ultimately, it's your OS and desktop environment job to show you that information.

Comment: @aadcg I work with 3 monitors. And make 3 Emacs frames. I don't want every time to turn my head to see what is the current keyboard layout :-)

Comment: Well, I tried and failed to get a method that would tell you (and emacs) what your keyboard layout is. The method I described works for me on Gnome, but it apparently does not work for you on Cinnamon. Unless you can provide such a method, there's not much that we can do here: as @aadcg says, it's  a matter of your desktop environment, so if I were you, I would ask for a CLI method at your favorite Cinnamon QA site.

Comment: @a_subscriber those are legitimate concerns. Imagine that you get a solution for the problem you posed. Then, how do you know which input method is selected in non-Emacs windows? In others words, I'm afraid you're approaching the issue from the wrong angle. Consider managing input methods (IM) from Emacs itself and you'll see on the modeline which IM is selected. I can also suggest another thing. If you're running the X window system, you can have the Caps Lock keyboard light turned on when an IM (in your case, RU) is selected. Search for smth along the lines of "grp_led:caps".